# Using the WHERE clause and not filtering a thing

Tags: php, sql

The WHERE clause is exists to help us filter the results, I'm getting from the user a value which tells me how to filter the results such as

```
WHERE brand="'$brand_that_chosen_by_user'"
```

One of the options is Every brand which means don't filter at all.
So what value $brand_that_chosen_by_user needs to be so the WHERE clause won't filter a thing and return All brands results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would first test if they selected the ALL value before adding the where clause.

```
$sql = " SELECT * FROM tbl";
if($brand != 'ALL'){
    $sql .= " WHERE brand = '{$brand}'";
}
```

Comment: I thought about it, I wanted to know if it possible to do that without asking that question. if not I will accept your answer.

Comment: That is the best way to do it, it's possible to do it with a weird complicated method, but this is the simple logical way.

Comment: @ShulyCohenPersiado - why don't you want to use an `if`?

Comment: I just wanted to know if it possible, I will accept your answer thanks.

Comment: Anything is possible. That's the beauty of programming.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a sql injection vulnerability. 
   `$brand_that_chosen_by_user = union select user,password from
   users`
2. You should consider just dropping the 'where' clause when the user selects "Every".

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

Either dynamically add the `WHERE` clause as needed:

```
if ($brand != 'Every brand') {
    $sql .= " WHERE brand = :brand";
}
```

Or make your SQL statement handle this as a special case:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE :brand = 'Every brand' OR brand = :brand
```

I'm using [PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) (to prevent SQL injection), so in both cases, you would need to bind the parameter with `$statement->bindParam("brand", $brand);`.